# qbo3 Search Panel override with XmlData

Tags: excel, xml, idatareader, qbo3

The QBO Deal modules includes a DealLoan panel that includes rendering user-defined fields. I wish to export the DealLoan data to Excel using a custom Excel template, but I don't know how to map the user-definded fields in the DealLoan.XmlData using QBO's [Excel overrides](https://dev.azure.com/quandisopensource/Documentation/_wiki/wikis/Documentation.wiki/324/Excel-Exports). Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcard field mapping in Excel to render XmlData.

There key configuration components to enable this are:

- The Excel template must include a range with a column like `XmlData_Root_*`
- Ensure `XmlStreamReader:PrefixNestedNames = true` is in configuration
- The `DealLoan` panel must use either `SearchXml` or `SmartSearch` to render data (this is the default configuration)

**Excel Template**

If you include a column name with asterisk(s), the `qbo4.Document.Aspose.Bridge.CellsHandler` will insert a new column for each field that matches the expression.  For example, given the following data:

```xml
<DealLoanCollection>
  <DealLoanItem>
    <DealLoanID>12345</DealLoanID>
    <DealLoan>1674063630</DealLoan>
    <XmlData>
      <Root>
        <Foo>Bar</Foo>
        <Animal>Road Runner</Animal>
      </Root>
    </XmlData>
  </DealLoanItem>
</DealLoanCollection>
```

```json
{
    "XmlStreamReader": {
        "PrefixNestedNames": true
    }
}
```

The following Excel range:

| DealLoanID | XmlData_Root_* | DealLoan |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |

would render the following:

| DealLoanID | Foo | Animal | DealLoan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Bar | Road Runner | 9999063630 |

Note that the "prefix" of the wildcard is, by default, removed from the resulting column name.  For example:

| Wildcard | Resulting Columns | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Xml* | _Data_Foo, _Data_Animal | Trailing * will omit everything before the `*. |
| Xml_* | Data_Foo, Data_Animal |  |
| *Loan | Deal | Leading * will omit everything after the *. |
| Deal* | LoanID, Loan |  |

> Caution: wildcard columns will trigger a column insert, which applies to an entire worksheet. If you have data above or below your target range, the column insert may cause unwanted side effects.

**XmlStreamReaderOptions**

QBO uses an `IDataReaderService` paired with an `XmlStreamReader` for this use case. The `XmlStreamReader` has options to control how nested XML fragments are rendered in a data reader, including:

| Property | Default | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PrefixNestedNames | `false` | If `true`, each ancestor node name will be included in the IDataReader field name. |
| PrefixDelimiter | `_` | Determines what ancestor nodes are concatenated with. |

These configuration changes can be set via any `IConfiguration` source your QBO environment is configured to read, including `ConfigurationEntry` or `AWS Secrets`.

**Warning**

Modifying the `XmlSreamReader` will impact the default behavior of all `XmlStreamReaders` created by the `IDataReaderService`, including imports. If you wish your imports to behave differently than the default behavior, you must extend your `ImportFileTemplate.Parameters` to include `PrefixNestedNames=true` or `PrefixNestedNames=false`. If the source data is not an `XmlStreamReader`, this setting will have no impact. If the source data is an `XmlStreamReader`, this setting will dictate the desired behavior.